# Add rows to a data frame based on date in previous row

Tags: r

I have a data frame `precip_range`:

```
start_date<-as.Date(c("2010-4-01", "2010-4-02", "2010-04-04", "2010-07-02", "2010-07-02", "2010-07-03"))  
end_date<-as.Date(c("2010-7-01", "2010-07-01", "2010-07-02", "2010-10-03", "2010-10-04", "2010-10-03"))
date_category<-(c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"))
site <-c("Site 1", "Site 2", "Site 3", "Site 1", "Site 2", "Site 3")
precip_range<-data.frame(site, start_date, end_date, date_category)
precip_range$days <-(end_date-start_date)
```

I would like to add a column `Date` and add rows with values of `Date` that fill in the date gaps between `start_date` and `end_date`by `site`. All columns except `Date` should retain the same information as in `precip_range`. I want the first few rows of the resulting data frame to look similar to the data frame `result_example`:

```
date<-as.Date(c("2010-04-01", "2010-04-02", "2010-04-03", "2010-04-04", "2010-04-05", "2010-04-06"))
result_date_category <-c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A")
result_site <-c("Site 1", "Site 1", "Site 1", "Site 1", "Site 1", "Site 1")
result_start_date <-as.Date(c("2010-04-01", "2010-04-01", "2010-04-01", "2010-04-01", "2010-04-01","2010-04-01"))
result_end_date <-as.Date(c("2010-07-01", "2010-07-01", "2010-07-01", "2010-07-01", "2010-07-01","2010-07-01"))
result_example <-data.frame(date, result_site, result_start_date, result_end_date, result_date_category)
result_example$days <-(result_end_date-result_start_date)
```

My question is similar to [[In R: Add rows with data of previous row to data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26487290/in-r-add-rows-with-data-of-previous-row-to-data-frame]), but I have not be able to successfully adapt that answer for my case. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
diffs <- with(precip_range, end_date - start_date + 1)
result_site <- precip_range[rep(seq_len(nrow(precip_range)), diffs), ]

library(data.table)
setDT(result_site)[, Date := seq.int(start_date[1], end_date[1], by = "day"), 
                     by = list(site, date_category)]
result_site

#        site start_date   end_date date_category    days       Date
#   1: Site 1 2010-04-01 2010-07-01             A 91 days 2010-04-01
#   2: Site 1 2010-04-01 2010-07-01             A 91 days 2010-04-02
#   3: Site 1 2010-04-01 2010-07-01             A 91 days 2010-04-03
#   4: Site 1 2010-04-01 2010-07-01             A 91 days 2010-04-04
#   5: Site 1 2010-04-01 2010-07-01             A 91 days 2010-04-05
# ---                                                              
# 551: Site 3 2010-07-03 2010-10-03             B 92 days 2010-09-29
# 552: Site 3 2010-07-03 2010-10-03             B 92 days 2010-09-30
# 553: Site 3 2010-07-03 2010-10-03             B 92 days 2010-10-01
# 554: Site 3 2010-07-03 2010-10-03             B 92 days 2010-10-02
# 555: Site 3 2010-07-03 2010-10-03             B 92 days 2010-10-03
```

Here we computed the date differences and performed *row indexing* according to the size of each difference. Afterwards, we added the date differences using `data.table` package (in order to improve performance)